# Unable to retain second attribute after sorting

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I have set4 variable(4 x 2 double). When I'm sorting it, the second attribute of each element also gets sorted. I just need to sort first attribute only.
For example,

```
set4=[ 10 1; 20 1; 5 2; 15 2];
sort(set4)
```

Output:

```
ans =

     5     1
    10     1
    15     2
    20     2
```

But my expected output is,
ans =

```
 5     2
10     1
15     2
20     1
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set4=[ 10 1; 20 1; 5 2; 15 2];  %example data
[set,in] = sort(set4(:,1));   %sort just the first column and get the indices
set(:,2)= set4(in,2)          %use the indices to re-order the second column
set =

 5     2
10     1
15     2
20     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set4=[ 10 1; 20 1; 5 2; 15 2];
sortrows(set4)

ans=

 5     2
10     1
15     2
20     1
```